# Angular: Using the exactly same component in 2 places

Tags: angular, components

I try to do a component which is used in 2 parts of the parent component.
To understand what I want to do, please check this:

```
<div class="root>
    <div class="for-desktop">
        <filter></filter>
    </div>
    <div class="for-mobile">
        <copy-of-filter></copy-of-filter>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want a single filter component to be in 2 different places without instancing 2 components. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you should ask yourself if you want the same component, or if you rather would have the exact same state shared between the two instances of the same component. If there is no way both instances are open at the same time, but you want to be able to switch between them, you got to make a service that tracks the state, and use the ngif solution dota2pro suggested

Answer (score 2):

> without instancing 2 components

I assume you want to know whether it is possible to have a singleton component in angular?
The answer to this question is no.

Directives and components (an angular component is also a directive) are not designed to be singletons. You can share a singleton service among them to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: ngOnInit is just a life cycle hook, it doesn't matter if you implement it or not, the component is initialized anyway.

Comment: @dota2pro, Im sorry I could not understand your point in the context of singletons. But as far as I know, even if a component is not projected into DOM because it is ngIf=false, it is initialized anyway. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: I see one console.log prompt when the page loads and the second when the component is rendered. So it is initialized even if it is not rendered but probably got destroyed and reinitialized when it is rendered.

Comment: @robert, I missed the first line :) Well, as far as I knew whether a component is rendered or not it was initilized. But seems like it is not. Well this comment thread is getting longer with considerably irrelevant topics about components. :)

Comment: @dota2pro, the second initialization belongs to a diferent instance. It does not have anything to do with being singleton.

Comment: @talhature my point is that you can control initialize of components. so `component to be in 2 different places without instancing 2 components` is possible.But any way I think the person who asked got his answer